# Older Plone site missing many stylesheets

Tags: plone

I have a Plone 4 site that was created 3 or 4 years ago and has had little maintenance since.  A third party installed a theme that I was never happy with, but since nobody else seemed to care I didn't pay much attention.  Now I've been hired to update the theme, and I see the real problem with the old site is that many of the standard .css files are not being included.

When I install the theme into a brand new Plone site, it looks good, but when I install it on the old site, `member.css`, for instance, is not loaded.

I can fix it by exporting the cssregistry.xml from portal_setup in the new site and loading it into the old site, but I'd rather find out why it's wrong as it is - what product should be installing **member.css**?  It looks as if it should be Products.CMFPlone (from Plone-4.0.7 in my case), so how would I force it to reinstall its registry?

[Edit: In fact, I did force it to reinstall it's registry by going to portal_setup **import** and reimporting the "Stylesheet Registry" step.  That broke my custom theme and some adapter (very odd, that), so I tried reimporting all steps and broke everything.  Good thing this is just a test copy!]

Comment: Why not just go into portal_css and reactivate the css?

Comment: @vangeem As I said, I _have_ the cssregistry.xml (which is exactly the same as using portal_css) but I want to _fix_ the problem, not just cover it up.

Comment: Alright, well, it'd help if you provided the cssregistry.xml file that is used for the theme you're trying to install. So to be sure, before you install the theme, member.css is included--it's just not until after you install it that it is removed. And this only happens on the old site, not a fresh plone site.

Comment: Also, you say, "I have a Plone 4 site that was created 3 or 4 years ago." I assume you mean that you upgraded to plone 4? Since plone 4 wasn't released 3 or 4 years ago....

Comment: maybe a more plain answer will help: member.css is part of the base profile and is installed on every site created unless you have someone specifically delete/disable it in portal_css or have a 3rd party product that does so. So the real fix IMO is probably re-enabling the css file in portal_css like I said not changing cssregistry.xml or running any import steps...

Comment: @vangeem Again, as I said, the _new_ site - with the theme installed - has no problems, therefore there is no interaction with _my_ theme. Something else - a product probably added and deleted in the meantime - has deleted the CSS.  What I'm looking for is exactly HOW to properly reinstall the original profile. Telling me to change portal_css and not mess with cssregistry.xml is contradictory - it's the SAME THING!  Perhaps just installing my cssregistry is the right thing to do, but it seems like a dirty hack to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an old and migrated site, I would just go into the ZMI and manually fix the problems. `member.css` has been part of core Plone itself since the beginning. So if that's not enabled someone did a manual change to your old site.

It's much easier to just fix the one broken site via the ZMI than to write any code or profiles to do it.

In my opinion it only makes sense to write GenericSetup profiles, if you do it all the way. So no changes via the ZMI or Plone control panels are allowed. You always have an extension profile in your policy code that will create a new site exactly mirroring the live site. You write upgrade steps for your own changes and run those instead of reapplying any profiles. You make sure to only use add-ons that are well behaved and use upgrade steps or you fix those to behave correctly.

But all of that costs time which only makes sense if you expect to change your site continuously and have tests for your site specific configuration. If you produce one-off sites that won't change anymore after they are deployed, this whole overhead is probably not worth it.

Comment: The key would seem to be "only use add-ons that are well behaved".  The biggest problem that I've found with Plone is the add-ons that are "fairly well behaved" - they do what you want, but you only find out about bad side-effects after you've had them in a live system a while (though whatever did this should have been obvious immediately!)

Answer (score 0):

If you had many tracebacks like

```
Traceback (innermost last):
  Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 126, in publish
  Module ZPublisher.mapply, line 77, in mapply
  Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 46, in call_object
Module zope.browserresource.file, line 202, in GET
Module zope.component._api, line 109, in getMultiAdapter
ComponentLookupError: ((<Products.Five.metaclass.DirContainedFileResource17 object at 0xde678ec>,
     <HTTPRequest, URL=http://127.0.0.1:8080/Plone/portal_css/Sunburst%20Theme/++resource++tinymce.stylesheets/tinymce.css>),
     <InterfaceClass zope.browserresource.interfaces.IETag>, u'')
```

and after reimporting  cssregistry.xml, had a broken layout with in the foreground Tracebacks looking like:

```
2011-10-10 08:42:32 ERROR Zope.SiteErrorLog 1318210952.260.0813518537427      http://127.0.0.1:8080/spirulinea/portal_css/Sunburst%20Theme/member.css
Traceback (innermost last):
Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 115, in publish
Module ZPublisher.BaseRequest, line 516, in traverse
Module ZPublisher.HTTPResponse, line 727, in debugError
NotFound:   Site Error
```

You may have fall in the same bug than me 
as it is said on http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/zms-developers/message/3674 
(for me as well) downgrading to  http://download.zope.org/Zope2/index/2.13.2 was the key.

[nota : as the time, I did not encounter any problem  with a fresh new Plone on the same instance of Zope, strangely enough .. so after all, may be your custom theme were not broken ]

Comment: Thanks for that - you could be right, but it's so long ago now, I can't be sure if I was getting errors like that (they wouldn't have been identical, as that theme wasn't using Sunburst).